# Select from ProblemFactCollectionProperty and PlanningEntityCollectionProperty in ShadowVariableListener like in ContraintProvider

Tags: optaplanner

For the update of my shadow variable I have to take into account some constraints which I can get from Objects saved in a ProblemFactCollectionProperty/PlanningEntityCollectionProperty.

Is it possible to select from ProblemFactCollectionProperty and PlanningEntityCollectionProperty inside of a ShadowVariableListener like it can be done with the ContraintProvider? Or do I have to add a pointer pointing to these collections to each object which has this shadow variable listener so that the listener can access the ProblemFactCollectionProperty/PlanningEntityCollectionProperty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods in `VariableListener` have a `ScoreDirector` parameter, so you can use `scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution()` to fetch your working solution.

Don't cache that solution instance or it's entity list instances in the VariableListener, as solution cloning might affect what's the real instance.